# Printing website loses it's css

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to print this website: http://www.florin-pop.com/work/Le%20Marais/
It's a simple layout with 2 columns, both of them containing tables.
The problem is that when I want to print them (for example using the js function `window.print()`, in the console) it doesn't respect the CSS styling. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you specify `media="screen"` in the CSS Link Attribute:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8"/>`

change `media="screen"` to `media="print"` OR `media="all"`

the media attribute allows you to target specific devices/situations with a stylesheet. So, you might have a `media="screen"` stylesheet for normal website, and a `media="print"` stylesheet specifically for printing out. A common use case is to switch to a black and white color scheme for print styles, or to ensure everything fits in a single column.

Here's some reading on media queries to get you started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: Glad to hear it! :) would appreciate it if you marked my answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I will once they let me :)

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it. Good luck with your future development :)